# Correct way to use tryCatch in R like iferror in excel

Tags: r, excel, try-catch

I know there are many other posts asking the same thing, but those questions are much too complicated and hard to understand. I am asking a barebones simple question. As far as I can tell I am supposed to use tryCatch in R as I would use iferror in excel.

BUT

```
tryCatch(add_feature,error={5})
```

should return 5 because add_feature does not exist. Instead tryCatch gives an error "Error in value[3L] : attempt to apply non-function"

This is not behaving like iferror in excel.

What is the correct function or method to simply make if behave exactly like iferror in excel?

In excel

```
=iferror(add_feature,5)
```

would return 5 if add_feature was not defined anywhere

define a cell with the name add_feature and type 10 in that cell

```
=iferror(add_feature,5)
```

would return 10

Thank you

Comment: `error` expects a function. Try: `tryCatch(add_feature,error=function(e){5})`
Here `e` is the error message that you might want to use (i.e. message(e))

Comment: that fixed it. thank you so much.